# cakephp validation doesn't work on save()

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am simply applying a validation rule in cakephp(2.x).When i save the data it saves into the database without validating the form.I am not able to find where i lack. I am beginner in cakephp. please suggest how can i validate my form. My form structure look like this.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="saveUser">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Register</legend>

        <span class = "error">* Required field</span>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name &nbsp;<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="name" placeholder="Name" required value="">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email&nbsp;<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email" required value="">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password&nbsp;<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password" required value="">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And Model validate array like this

```
public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'Only Allows Letter and Numbers'
        ),
        'between' => array(
            'rule' => array('lengthBetween', 5, 15),
            'message' => 'length upto 5 to 15 character'
        )
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'rule' => array('minLength', '8'),
        'message' => 'Password Too Short'
    ),
    'email' => 'email',
);
```

and the controller like

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
    if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Employee Registration Successfully'));
        $this->redirect(['action'=>'viewAdminDashboard']);

    }
    else{
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Cannot Register Employee'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP cannot match input fields with model columns if you assign your own names. For instance:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="name" placeholder="Name" required value="">
                                                             ^^^^
```

... should be

```
name="data[User][name]"
```

If you're using CakePHP for model and controller, it'd be easier to just use it for views as well:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('name');
```

I highly recommend the [Blog Tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html).